# Can I copy a compressed file from one Zip file to another without decompressing and recompressing it?

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib

I am currently using SharpZipLib for reading/writing ZIP files in C#.  Often I want to create a new ZIP file, containing some of the files from an old ZIP file.  How can I copy entries between ZIP files without decompressing and recompressing the data?

Comment: did you find out a way to do this?

Comment: @CoderM, no :-(